# Using value of cell with formula returns Type Missmatch

Tags: vba, excel

I have an `IFERROR` formula in a cell (let's say A1), which returns "" when there is an error. Therefore, the cell is "blank", when an error occurs. When I try to use the value of that cell, for example by doing `Cells(1,1)=Cells(1,1).Value+1`, I get a Type Missmatch error. If I delete the formula and leave the cell blank, then I don't get that error. Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Because there is a difference between a formula putting in a null string which is a string and a blank cell which equals 0 by default.

Comment: According to your `IFERROR` formula, value of blank cell is not a number.  So `"" + 1` leads to a type mismatch.

Comment: The best thing would be to put 0 instead of a "".  Then you would not have this issue.

Comment: What if I have to leave the "" in the formula. Is there a different way to fix it?

Comment: in addition to @ScottCraner comment, use Number formatting to specifically hide the 0. format could be like `0;-0;"";@`. The "" in the key to hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"" + 1` is not accepted by VBA because one is a character, one is a number.

You can either:

- Have `IFERROR` return 0 instead of "" to avoid type mismatches
- use an `if` statement to check for "":

  ```
  If Cells(1,1) = "" Then 
       Cells(1,1) = 1
  Elseif IsNumeric(Cells(1,1)) Then
       Cells(1,1) = Cells(1,1).Value + 1
  End If
  ```
- convert "" to 0:

  ```
  Cells(1,1) = Val(Cells(1,1).Value) + 1
  ```

Comment: Any other way? Like converting the string into a number?

Comment: `If Cells(1,1) = "" Then Cells(1,1).Value = 0` - something like that?

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I meant. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't like Val, it will turn 34,10 into 3410 wouldn't it? Which might be inappropriate for European decimal systems. Use CInt or Cdbl ?

Comment: @CodyG. `CInt("")` and `CDbl("")` also will give type mismatch errors. `Val("")` works fine when dealing with pseudo-blanks like `""` cells.

Comment: Is that so? If it turns doubles into some different number, then it's not useful.

Comment: @N.Pavon It works with 32.56 but I'm not entirely sure what it does with 32,56.

Comment: looks like `Val("32,56")` returns 32.